# Trying to get column index from textbox in column header of table JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the column index number for the table from the textbox in each table header.

```
$("[id*=TXTSEARCH]").keyup(function () {
           
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            tablename = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
            mytd = $(this).closest('td');
             alert(mytd.index());

        })
```

This keeps returning all the same numbers. -1

Here is my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/u8fjo2gv/1/

Comment: It is because your `input` fields are placed in `th` tags, not in `td` tags. Try using `closest('th')` instead.

Comment: instead of index, you should set [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the element or input boxes.

Comment: @Tom you are correct!